# Hook two horizontal slider each other - PyQt5

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-3, pyqt5

In my QGIS Plugin I have this Qt dialog where there are two horizontal sliders. I'm trying to hook one to the other in this way: if the checkBox is checked, I take the difference between them and if one is moved the other change the value using the difference. This is the code I tried, but it does not work.

```
def run (self):
   self.dlg = Dialog()
   if self.dlg.checkBox.isChecked():
      firstDate = self.dlg.horizontalSlider.value()
      secondDate = self.dlg.horizontalSlider_2.value()
      difference = abs(secondDate-firstDate)
      self.dlg.horizontalSlider.sliderMoved.connect(self.dlg.horizontalSlider_2.setValue(firstDate+difference))
      self.dlg.horizontalSlider_2.sliderMoved.connect(self.dlg.horizontalSlider.setValue(secondDate-difference))
   self.dlg.show()
```

This is the dialog to be more clear:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Test-it in another method like that :

```py
def run (self):
   self.dlg = Dialog()
   self.dlg.horizontalSlider.sliderMoved.connect(lambda v: self.adjust_sliders(1, v))
   self.dlg.horizontalSlider_2.sliderMoved.connect(lambda v: self.adjust_sliders(2, v))
   self.dlg.show()

def adjust_sliders(self, slider_num, moved_value):
   if self.dlg.checkBox.isChecked():
      firstDate = self.dlg.horizontalSlider.value()
      secondDate = self.dlg.horizontalSlider_2.value()
      difference = abs(secondDate-firstDate)

   if slider_num == 1:
      self.dlg.horizontalSlider_2.sliderMoved.disconnect()
      self.dlg.horizontalSlider_2.setValue(firstDate+difference)
      self.dlg.horizontalSlider_2.sliderMoved.connect(lambda v: self.adjust_sliders(1, v))
   if slider_num == 2:
      self.dlg.horizontalSlider.sliderMoved.disconnect()
      self.dlg.horizontalSlider.setValue(secondDate-difference)
      self.dlg.horizontalSlider.sliderMoved.connect(lambda v: self.adjust_sliders(2, v))
```

<strike>But beware, if you move slider 1, slider 2 will move that will move slider 1, etc. This will cause an infinite recursion.</strike>

It's normally now corrected.

Comment: Thanks, do you have any idea to avoid the recursion problem?

Comment: @Lorenzo: yes, disconnect the signal before setting the new value, reconnect it just after. Your solution is false, connect the signals only in the `run` part.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know what this means. Could you show me how to do that? Thanks again

Comment: See my post edit.

Comment: Many thanks, now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to J. Monticolo suggestion, I solved in this way.

```
def run(self):  
  self.dlg = Dialog() 
  self.dlg.checkBox.stateChanged.connect(lambda: self.takeDifference())
  self.dlg.show()     

def takeDifference(self):
  if self.dlg.checkBox.isChecked():
    firstDate = self.dlg4.horizontalSlider.value()
    secondDate = self.dlg4.horizontalSlider_2.value()
    difference = abs(secondDate-firstDate)
    self.dlg.horizontalSlider.sliderMoved.connect(lambda: self.adjust_sliders(1,difference))
    self.dlg.horizontalSlider_2.sliderMoved.connect(lambda: self.adjust_sliders(2,difference))

def adjust_sliders(self, slider_num,difference):
  if self.dlg.checkBox.isChecked():
    firstDate = self.dlg.horizontalSlider.value()
    secondDate = self.dlg.horizontalSlider_2.value()
    if slider_num == 1:
      self.dlg.horizontalSlider_2.valueChanged.disconnect()
      self.dlg.horizontalSlider_2.setValue(firstDate+difference)
      self.dlg.horizontalSlider_2.valueChanged.connect(lambda: self.adjust_sliders(1,difference))
    if slider_num == 2:
       self.dlg.horizontalSlider.valueChanged.disconnect()
       self.dlg.horizontalSlider.setValue(secondDate-difference)
       self.dlg.horizontalSlider.valueChanged.connect(lambda: self.adjust_sliders(2,difference))
```